# How to play specific audio file in voice channel?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm pretty new to javascript and discord.js, does anyone know how to make a bot join a channel, play a file and leave?

Here's what I've tried:

```
    if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "vc")){
        var voiceChannel = msg.member.voiceChannel; 
        isReady = false;
        if (!voiceChannel)
            return msg.channel.send("Join a VC.")
        else voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            const dispatcher = connection.playFile('./audio/audio.mp3');
            dispatcher.on("end", end => voiceChannel.leave());
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
})
```

Right now, it will send the message to join a voice channel regardless of whether I am in one or not, and if I am it doesn't join the voice channel and play the file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using 14.3.0 of node.js.

Comment: Please read what's asked carefully, I didn't ask for your node.js version

Comment: Sorry, I'm using 12.2.0 of discord.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since discord.js v12, `GuildMember.voiceChannel` was changed to `GuildMember.voice.channel`

```js
var voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel
```